# Is the DAYOFWEEK culture dependant in bigquery?

Tags: date, google-bigquery

When extracting the day of the week as shown below, will the Sunday always be the first day of the week or will the result vary depending on some culture or other setting?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATETIME()), CURRENT_DATETIME()
```

I couldn't get the confirmation or denial from the [documention of the EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#extract)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM date_expression) says that Sunday is always the first day of the week. It seems unlikely the result would be different for EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM datetime_expression), but it would be nice to have documentation of that.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions